# How do i change the name of menu 'Admin' in Mean.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I am using mean.js for my app, and when I log in as admin I see a Menu 'Admin' showing up, which I would like to change it's name to Users.

In user/client/config/users-admin.client.menus.js I have:

```
'use strict';

// Configuring the Articles module
angular.module('users.admin').run(['Menus',
    function (Menus) {
        Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'admin', {
            title: 'Manage Users',
            state: 'admin.users'
        });

    }
]);
```

This is just for the sub-menu, but I dont see an option to change the 'Admin'.

How do I achieve such thing, is it possible?

I have attached also a screenshot of what I mean.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWpSa.png)

Comment: I'm guessing that must be in another file - perhaps another JS file like this one or else maybe hardcoded into an HTML template.

Comment: @JosiahKeller, I am sure it should be somewhere too! but I was asking if someone knows for sure where it is!

Comment: found it, it was under core module, core-admin.client.menus.js